# Random numbers but they should only appear x times in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add 0 or 1 as numbers (randomly) in a lot of cells (in different rows and columns). For example:

```
0  1  1  1 0  0 0 0
1  1  0  0 0  1 1 0
```

But I want those numbers be added up to five times in a row. For example: if the row has 10 cells which the random numbers will go, I don't want the 1 or 0 to be added a sixth time so I am looking to something like this: `0  1  1  1 0  1  1 0 0 0`

Comment: I'm unsure about what you want. What about `=SORTBY(ROUND(SEQUENCE(1,10,0,0.1),0),RANDARRAY(1,10))`

Comment: @JvdV I think what they want is basically to start with the array `{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1}`, and then randomise the order of the contents that array, and Fill it into the Row.  So, there are always 5 `1`s and 5 `0`s

Comment: @Chronocidal, as per my 1st comments suggested formula then. Will wait for OP to confirm. Going by the current information this could still go in several directions.

Comment: I want to have random numbers between 0 and 1 but also to be able to control how many times 0 or 1 can show up in a row. For example if i have a row with 7 cells,  I don't want the number 1 to be able to show up 6 times (even if the possibility is low). I want to be able to choose for example up to 3 times for 1 and up to 4 times for 0. Thank you for your answers i will try your suggestions.

Comment: I've re-written my answer to account for this new requirement.

Comment: Something like `=SORTBY(MID(REPT(1,3)&REPT(0,4),SEQUENCE(1,7),1),RANDARRAY(1,7))` then?

Comment: The answer provided from CLR works for me. I will take in mind to use markdown table generator in the future. Thank you all for taking the time to help me. I will also try your suggestions and update the thread here if they are also can be applied to my question.

Comment: @Ike The question has contained 3 Expected Outputs — and a text description of what qualifies as an Expected Output — since the moment it was posted.  It also explains that the inputs are "Number of Columns in the Row", and "Number of Columns that should contain a 1", beyond which there **isn't** any data to *provide* a sample of.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your latest comment, the following code would work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rw As Range
    For Each rw In Range("A1:J116").Rows
        create_binary rw, 5
    Next
End Sub

Sub create_binary(rng As Range, one_count As Long)
    With rng
        .ClearContents
        Do Until Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells) = one_count
            .Cells(Int(.Count * Rnd + 1)) = 1
        Loop
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

It contains a subroutine called `create_binary` which needs two parameters:

- The cells to write to (`rng`)
- The total value you want those cells to reach (`one_count`)

Comment: I think that's exactly what i want. Thank you for your answer. Let me test it in a real environment so I can be sure.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work as i thought it should. If i have a range for example (A1:J116) your code adds the "1"  five times to all those cells and not per row. The result is the code run in 1160 cells (10 per row) but it has only five "1" and not five per row, so we have about 1155 zeros..

Comment: See addition I just made to my answer that will write to each row of a range, row by row.

Comment: Maybe i am not adding  it in the right place but it gets stuck after running it.

Comment: Hello CLR sorry if i am being forceful. Thank you for all your help. Can you copy paste the whole code? My excel hangs when i add your new addition.

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how to use the script based on your latest requirement.